# Java how to determine Square contains another shapes inside

Tags: java

In squre2d plane class...

i need logic to calculate shape is inside the square or outide......
shape contain point (x,y ) which can be circle center or topleft point of square
and a double length which can be circle radius or side length of square...
How to identify  given circle is inside the square or outside....
         and square is inside the  square or outside....

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but I *think* that you're asking how to determine the type of `Shape` that something is.

Given some `Shape s`, you can determine its type not by checking the equality to a subclass of `Shape`, but by using the `instanceof` keyword, like so:

`if (s instanceof Circle) { ... }`

Once you do this, you can cast `s` as a `Circle` and perform the operations on it as if it were a `Circle`.

```
if (s instanceof Circle) {
  Circle c = (Circle) s;
  // Do what you have to do to c
  s = c;
}
```

Comment: i am sorry being unclear .... i have idea about casting object i need logic to check weather given circle shape or square shape inside of a square or not ....... @wadda_wadda